# Image Hover Scaling

Tags: css, scale

I have am image I wish to scale but leave the footprint the same size as original. CSS transition scale works great except my image not only grows in size, the footprint also expands so that the entire image shows, just larger.

HTML

```
 <p class="secondCol">
    <span class="columnTitle">Seller Services</span>
    <a href="sellers.html" style="padding-top: 0em;">
    <img src="_images/engaged-buying-a-home.jpg" class="grow">
 </p>
```

CSS

```
.grow {
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

.grow:hover {
    transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by footprint in this context?

Comment: transform is only a visual effect, DOM structure won't change, so nothing will grow with the image

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. Assume the photo is 300px X 200px. I want the newly scaled image to occupy the same space on the webpage (300x200) but be scaled to a larger size. In now scales to the larger size and takes up more space on the webpage.

Comment: put it inside a container and hide the overflow